# How to dynamically set a menu item class name with MVC4?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

For a new application we are using Bootstrap v3.0, which has the navigation menu defined as follows:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="dashboard.html"><i class="icon-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
        <li class="submenu">
            <a href="#"><i class="icon-beaker"></i> <span>UI Lab</span> <i class="arrow icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="interface.html">Interface Elements</a></li>
                <li><a href="jquery-ui.html">jQuery UI</a></li>
                <li><a href="buttons.html">Buttons &amp; icons</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu">
            <a href="#"><i class="icon-th-list"></i> <span>Form elements</span> <i class="arrow icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="form-common.html">Common elements</a></li>
                <li><a href="form-validation.html">Validation</a></li>
                <li><a href="form-wizard.html">Wizard</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>...
```

This is currently sitting in a shared _Layout.cshtml, and don't currently see a need to move this into its own shared view.

The layout template consists of several static files with `<li class="active">` hard coded for the corresponding menu item within that file.

Since I'm building this with MVC4, I would like to know how to dynamically set this, based on the view being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure best practice on this. You could try something like this:

```
<li class="@( RouteVariable.CurrentController.Equals("Home") ? "active" : "")">
```

Or RouteVariables.CurrentAction may be of use.